# How to retrieve file content from Javascript readEntries()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, file-upload

I'm implementing a directory drag and drop on my web application, I receive the event and get the corresponding `entry` by calling `webkitGetAsEntry()`. Then I check the `entry` object: if it's a directory I proceed to list all the files.

```
  var entry = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry();
  if (entry.isDirectory) {
        var reader = entry.createReader();
        reader.readEntries(function(entries){
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
              alert(entry.fullPath);
        });
  });
```

At this point I'm able to get only the filename, what I'd like to have is also the file content but apparently the array returned by `readEntries()` doesn't include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var entry = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].webkitGetAsEntry();
if (entry.isDirectory) {
    var reader = entry.createReader();
    reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
        const files = entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                entry.file(
                    function(file) {
                        resolve(file);
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                );
            });
        });

        Promise.all(files).then(function(fileData) {
            //do something with the data
            console.log(fileData);
        });
    });
}
```